# С какой точки считается margin-left?

Tags: css

С какого угла? Или с середины?

Comment: От... того места, где начинался бы элемент к которому применили это плавило?

Answer (score 0):

С того элемента, который обрамляет текущий элемент. Пример

```css
p.ex1 {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
div {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Свойство  margin-left</h1>
<div>
<p>Абзац без отступов.</p>
<p class="ex1">Абзац с отступами 30 пикселей.</p>
<p>Абзац без отступов.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: А если это div с картинкой в background

Comment: значит  это `div.left`

Answer (score 0):

Margin — это поле, которое обрамляет элемент. Поэтому он не «откуда», а «вокруг» чего и каким размером. А сверху/снизу/слева/справа определяется свойством margin-top/bottom/right/left.